# Nothing happens when calling Google Endpoint from Android App with credential

Tags: android, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I encounter problems  when calling Google Endpoint from Android App with credential ONLY.
My google API is protected with AUTH (clientIds, audiences) provided in API Endpoint.

When calling  this API in android APP, if I do not provide Google credential when building the end point :

```
Enduserendpoint.Builder builder = new Enduserendpoint.Builder(
       AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), null);
```

Then I call the API 'execute' method, it works since I receive from the server an AuthException which is right since no credential I provide. If I check the server logs, I could see the call to the API which results with this exception.

Problem is now when I provide a credential :

```
Enduserendpoint.Builder builder = new Enduserendpoint.Builder(
       AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential);
```

Then when execute() a method from API ==> NOTHING happens

- No error receive
- Call to API method not made
- Nothing in server logs that tells me there was a call

I had a look many hours and do not find what's happening ... and I dont know how I could check where the problem is since my Android app does not give me any error logs and nothing about the call in the server logs ... and when credential is null in the builder ... all works well since the server reacts with an AuthException.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm having the same problem now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloud endpoints authentication failure in android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263228/cloud-endpoints-authentication-failure-in-android-app)

Comment: Hello, I'm a representative of Google Cloud Support. Are you still having this issue? If so, could you share the ID of your project to open a case to follow up with it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem.

Everything works fine if I use endpoint with a null credential, but if I use a non-null credential, app-engine receive nothing, even I use an api which needs no User parameter.

Finally, I found that I cannot test directly with android sdudio. I have to sign my apk and install it manually to test an endpoint api which needs a User parameter.